# What is the difference between "termination status" and "end status" as returned from waitpid?

Tags: c, unix, process, posix, system-calls

In *Operating Systems Design and Implementation* by Andrew S. Tanenbaum and Albert S. Woodhull, there's the following fragment:

> "[...] consider exit, which processes should use when they are finished executing. It has one parameter, the exit status (0 to 255), which is returned to the parent via statloc [as in waitpid(int, int *statloc, int)] in the waitpid system call. The **low-order byte of status contains the termination status**, with 0 being normal termination and the
>   other values being various error conditions. **The high-order byte contains the child's exit status (0
>   to 255).**"

So, what's the difference between the concepts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exit status is what the process itself provided in a call to `exit` (or the return value from `main`, which is defined to be the same thing as calling `exit`).

But that's not the only way a process can be terminated. In particular, it can be terminated by a signal, which is what will happen if the program segfaults, or divides by zero, or if some other process sends it a kill signal. In those cases, there is no exit status because the program was never able to call `exit()`. The termination status, then, indicates whether the program called `exit()`, or, if not, the number of the signal which resulted in termination. There are likely to also be some implementation-specific flags; for example, Linux sets a flag in the termination status if the program terminated by a signal created a core dump.

See `main waitpid` for the macros you can use to extract this information from the status value returned by `waitpid`.

Answer (score 3):

The **exit status** refers to the value that a processes passed to the `exit` function (or returned from `main`) on normal program termination.

The **termination status** refers to what caused the program to end or stop.  In other words, whether it exited normally (as mentioned above), or was terminated by a signal.  This can also indicate if the processes was stopped (but not terminated) by a signal, or if it continued after being stopped.  This can happen when a process is being debugged.