# How to interpret process termination status issued by waitpid function

Tags: c, process, waitpid

I am debugging the following code :

```
if(0 == (pid = fork()))
{
    if(-1 == execv(p_Command[0], (char **)p_Command))
    {
        ret = -1;
        printf("Fork error on command '%s'", (nullptr == p_Command[0])?"nullptr":p_Command[0]);
    }
}
// Fork error
else if(-1 == pid)
{
    printf("Fork error on command '%s'", (nullptr == p_Command[0])?"nullptr":p_Command[0]);
    ret = -1;
}
// In parent process
else
{
    // Wait for child
    while((0 == waitpid(pid , &status , WNOHANG)) && (timeout != 0))
    {
        if(timeout > 0)
        {
            --timeout;
            sleep(1);
        }
    }

    TRACE("after wait pid = %d", pid);

    TRACE("status = %d", status);

    if(1 != WIFEXITED(status))
    {
        ret = -1;
        printf("WIFEXITED error");
    }
    else if(0 != WEXITSTATUS(status))
    {
        ret = -1;
        printf("WEXITSTATUS error");
    }

    else
    {
        ret = pid;
    }
}
return ret;
```

}

My principal concern is about the waitpid function, it is returning a status of 65280 and so WEXITSTATUS(status) evaluates to 254. I am trying to understand why it is evaluating to that value and why the author wants it to evaluate to 0 for a success return.

Does anyone have a clue?

I read in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61980810/what-is-the-difference-between-termination-status-and-end-status-as-returned) post that WEXITSTATUS(status) evaluates to a value between 0 and 255, but I haven't till now found any information about the meaning associated to those values so that I can investigate on why the macro evaluates to 255

Comment: What's telling you that `WEXITSTATUS(status)` is 254? From 65280, it should be 0.

Comment: "*why it is evaluating to that value and why the author wants it to evaluate to 0 for a success return*". Why not? Every well defined program will specify what it returns and what each return value means. You need to read the manual/documentation for each command to know what it means. But a common convention is 0 for success and -1 or some other non-zero value for failure.

Comment: @ThomasJager , I have this definition `#define  __WEXITSTATUS(status) (((status) & 0xff00) >> 8)`. As status is 65280 thus 0xff00, WEXITSTATUS(status) is 255 (and not 254 as I firstly mentioned)

Comment: @kaylum I agree with you on specifying returns. But my concern here is about interpreting the returned value. I searched but found no documentation. Would you have to recomment?

Comment: Interpreting the return value depends on what you are running. We don't know the commands you are running but presumably it should have documentation. For example, if `p_Command[0]` is `"ls"` then you need to read the [ls manual](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ls.1.html). It will tell you what the return values mean.

Answer (score 0):

The parameter `wstatus` contains two states:

- termination status (normal or abnormal termination)
- exit status (only valid on normal termination)

With the macro `WIFEXITED` you test the termination status and with the macro `WEXITSTATUS` you extract the exit status (the code passed to `exit` or returned from the `main` function).

See [man wait](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/wait.2.html)

> **WIFEXITED**(*wstatus*)
>  returns true if the child terminated normally, that is, by calling exit(3) or _exit(2), or by returning from main().

> **WEXITSTATUS**(*wstatus*)
> returns the exit status of the child.  This consists of
> the least significant 8 bits of the status argument that
> the child specified in a call to exit(3) or _exit(2) or as
> the argument for a return statement in main().  This macro
> should be employed only if WIFEXITED returned true.

From the link you've posted:

> ...
>
> The low-order byte of status contains the termination status, with 0 being normal termination and the other values being various error conditions. The high-order byte contains the child's exit status (0 to 255)."

And lastly, the author tests if the return value (exit value - normal termination) is `0`, which by convention stands for **success**.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is there a way to know why a certain value is returned? In my case 255

Comment: No. Because other than `0` (`EXIT_SUCCESS`) and `-1` (`EXIT_FALURE`), it could mean anything. Only the author knows, what that specific value means.

Comment: `EXIT_SUCCESS` and `EXIT_FAILURE` are defined in `stdlib.h`. See: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/program/EXIT_status